# Unable to get Spring MVC Hello World to work

Tags: spring-mvc

I tried the various suggestions that were given but could not get my Spring MVC Hello World application to work. Could someone help me out with the same?

Following is the content of my files:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml (just the dependencies part)**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**spring.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.aditya.controllers" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

**My controller class**

```
@Controller
public class FirstController
{
    @RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
    public String greetUser(final ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!!!");
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

**helloWorld.jsp (placed at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp)**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Update: I now have the flow going to my controller. However, I am not able to forward the user to the view. I get the following in my console Jul 08, 2016 1:57:03 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/application-two/WEB-INF/jsp/helloWorld.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this. Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by modifying the web.xml to:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Notice the change in the url-pattern of the servlet-mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 missing configurations.

<del>In **web.xml**, you missed `ContextLoaderListener`.</del>

<del>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    

    
    ...</del>

In your **spring.xml**, you missed controller component scan configuration. Suppose your FirstController is in package `com.example.web.controller`.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web.controller"></context:component-scan>
```

You can refer to Spring documentation for configuration details. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet

Comment: Edited my question. I was able to get most of the errors to be resolved by just using the same version of spring-core as spring-web and spring-webmvc. Also, adding the `<context:component-scan>` was required. Not sure about the ContextLoaderListener. I think the contextConfigLocation should be doing the needful.

Comment: @AdityaGupta You're right it's my misunderstanding and fault. `ContextLoaderListener` is definitely not a must and you can get rid of it. I'll edit my answer.